# C# Microsoft Graph SDK - Paging limits

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have investigated that if I use a search filter as follows:

```
string filter = String.Format("\"subject:\"");

List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
    new QueryOption("$search", filter)
};

var messages = graphClient.Me
    .MailFolders
    .Inbox
    .Messages
    .Request(options)
    .Top(500)
    .Select("id, Categories, Subject")
    .GetAsync()
    .Result;
```

Despite me using `Top(500)`, the results cut off at `275`, I think there is a page limit associated with the search filter, does anyone know how to workaround this in the SDK?

If I do not include options in the messages query i.e. if I do `Request()`, I get all messages.

Note that the `Messages.NextPageProperty` also seems to return null so I cannot use this.

Answer (score 2):

This is how the `$search` parameter works. From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter):

> **Note:** You can currently search **only** `message` and `person` collections. A `$search` request returns up to `250` results. You cannot use `$filter` or `$orderby` in a search request.